# CakePHP3 Collection each iterator not modifying items

Tags: cakephp, collections, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to add a 'modelType' property to each item in a collection. However, it doesnt seem to be showing up afterward:

```
$results->each(function($row, $index) use ($modelType) {
   $row['modelType'] = $modelType;
});

debug($results->toArray()); //<---- modelType isn't listed in any of my items
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
In my example code, $results was generated by a Query with hydrate set to false, which returns arrays rather than entities.

Took out the ->hydrate(false) and then the each loop modified the Collection as expected.